# Excel VBA to add unique numbers to multiple accounts

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I cannot get to a satisfactory answer.  I need to add comments to a data input sheet. I have added a form  and I am able to populate my worksheet.  However, I wish to add a unique identifier (number) to each unique customer. Row a1 has customer A; row a2 has customer B; row a3 has customer A - I would like to number the rows 1, 1, 2 respectively in column b

Comment: Don't you mean 1, 2, 1 to match A, B, A ?

Comment: Okay? What have you tried? What has/hasn't worked? Why can't you just add the number to your comment? What does your data look like?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have your customers in column `A` and your unique numbers in column `B` you could use the following formula for cell `B2` and then copy it down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:B1,MATCH(A2,$A$1:A1,0)),MAX($B$1:B1)+1)
```

<sub>Cell `B1` will be set to 1 or whichever the starting number should be.</sub>

The result would be something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If by "add a unique identifier (number) to each unique customer" you mean that you are trying to generate a sequence number which is unique within each unique customer, (i.e. if column A contained A, B, A, C, C then you are after 1, 1, 2, 1, 2 in column B) then you can just use the formula

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)
```

in cell B1 and copy it down.